# Installed python module is not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, python, aptitude

This borders on stackoverflow/superuser, but I guess it's a simple installation problem.

I've installed python-twisted on my ubuntu 10.04 server, but it can't be found.

This is what I get when I try to import something:

```
>>> from twisted.internet import reactor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "twisted.py", line 1, in 
    from twisted.internet import reactor
ImportError: No module named internet
```

I've installed the package through apt-get.
That way the module is installed in this folder: `/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted`
with an `__init__.py` file.

When I try to use `python setup.py install` (on the download from the site) it installs it to `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted`, but it also does not find it there.

Does anyone know where it went wrong? Google isn't spilling anything.

Comment: Does just `import twisted` work?

Comment: How did you install python-twisted? `apt-get`, `easy_install`, `setup.py install`?

Comment: I installed it through apt-get, yeah. Didn't really see the point in doing it through setup.py. And since nobody else has ever reported this problem with twisted before I thought I must be doing something wrong.

Just importing twisted also does not work. It gives the same error "ImportError: No module named internet"

Comment: The package from apt-get installs twisted into the `/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted` directory, with a __init__.py file in it. So that should work!

To test it out, I removed it and installed it through `python setup.py install`but it installed it into `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a twisted.py file that shadows the correct imports. Rename it. You can use absolute imports (`from __future__ import absolute_imports`), if you want your own module to be available as `myapp.twisted`.